# Return the count of data saved in a column and displayed in two different columns

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ms-access, select

I have a table in which a column contains two variables and I want to return the count of each of them in two columns

| name | type |
| --- | --- |
| A | outgoing |
| B | incoming |
| B | incoming |
| B | outgoing |
| C | incoming |
| B | incoming |
| A | outgoing |

I need to do this

| Name | count Outgoing | count incoming |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2 | 0 |
| B | 1 | 3 |
| C | 0 | 1 |

Comment: Access of SQL server? Please show your attempt.

Comment: Btw... you have your terminology mixed up a bit.  You have a table of two columns and multiple rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could group by the `name` and then have two `sum` calls over `case` expressions for the `type`. Using `sum` to simulate a `count` takes care of having to `coalesce` if a name has no incoming or outgoing types:

```sql
SELECT   name, 
         SUM(CASE type WHEN 'outgoing' THEN 1 ELSE 0END) AS count_outgoing,
         SUM(CASE type WHEN 'incoming' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count_incoming
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY name
```